# Database connection spring framework unresolved

Tags: java, spring

i had earlier created the spring framework, then replaced with the database connection, but there is problem in creating the beans.

also receiving the below error during the deployment.

> DEFAULT=C:\Users\gopc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloSpringJDBC\build\web&name=HelloSpringJDBC&contextroot=/HelloSpringJDBC&force=true
>   failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2   Error occurred during deployment:
>   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'productManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'productDao' of bean class [SimpleProductManager]: Bean
>   property 'productDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?. Please see server.log for more details.
>   C:\Users\gopc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloSpringJDBC\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1029:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

**Source**

applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="externalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="singleton"     destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C://Users//gopc//Documents//odbc_sql.accdb"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="productManager" class="SimpleProductManager">
        <property name="productDao" ref="productDao"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="productDao" class="JdbcProductDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="externalDataSource"/>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

### **spirngapp-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean name="/hello.htm" class="HelloController"> 
            <property name="productManager" ref="productManager"/>    
    </bean>       


    <!-- we can prefix="/" 
    http://localhost:8080/HelloSpring/hello.htm
    specify the path in  modelview from the controller 
                        OR
    Decouple the view from the controller                    
    prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    -->

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">  
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>  
    </bean> 
            <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

**JdbcProductDao.java**

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcDaoSupport;


public class JdbcProductDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements ProductDao {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 

     public List<Product> getProductList() {
        logger.info("Getting products!");
        List<Product> products = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(
                "select id, description, price from products", 
                new ProductMapper());
        return products;
    } 



      public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        logger.info("Saving product: " + prod.getDescription());
        int count = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(
            "update products set description = :description, price = :price where id = :id",
            new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("description", prod.getDescription())
                .addValue("price", prod.getPrice())
                .addValue("id", prod.getId()));
        logger.info("Rows affected: " + count);
    }

      private static class ProductMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Product> { 
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            prod.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            prod.setPrice(new Double(rs.getDouble("price")));
            return prod;
        } 
    } 
}
```

**SimpleProductManager.java**

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class SimpleProductManager implements ProductManager { 

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 

    private ProductDao productDao;

    public List<Product> getProductDao() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        return productDao.getProductList();
    } 
    public void increasePrice(int percentage) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();        

            List <Product> products = productDao.getProductList();
            for (Product product : products) {
                double newPrice = product.getPrice() * (100 + percentage)/100;
                product.setPrice(newPrice);
                productDao.saveProduct(product);
            }
    } 

    public void setProductDao(ProductDao productDao) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();     
        logger.info("inside the setProducts in SimpleProductManager");
        this.productDao = productDao;

    } 
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; 

import java.io.IOException;



public class HelloController implements Controller { 

    private ProductManager productManager; 
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 

    /*
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

            throws ServletException, IOException { 

        logger.info("Returning hello view"); 
        String now = ( new Date().toString());
        logger.info("time now:"+ now);

        //return new ModelAndView("hello");


        //return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/hello","now",now);

        //decouple the view from the controller
        return new ModelAndView("hello","now",now);
    } 
    */

    //Writing some business logic in the controller

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String now = (new java.util.Date()).toString();

        logger.info("returning hello view with " + now); 
        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        myModel.put("now", now);
        myModel.put("products", this.productManager.getProductDao()); 
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);
    }

    public void setProductManager(ProductManager productManager) 
    {
        this.productManager = productManager;
    } 

}
```

Comment: @mael I know I would help but if you look at his past questions I feel like he abuses SO... just paste a bunch of files an say here fix it.

Comment: @Gopal....When some one gives a useful answer to your question, try to accept rather than simply asking questions....

Comment: i could not able to find the "accept" button, could you let me where does it exists.

Answer (score -1):

hey the problem got resovled, after i had modified, the following..

1) applicationContext with mapping for the bean "productManager" with ref productDao.

2) ProductManager interface with new method call getProducts(), then implemenent in the SimpleProductManager and which call the ProductDao.getProducts(), where the sql query is being defined.